# Linking JSLink from outside of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, jslink

I'm creating and app which adds text field with custom JSLink.
Everything works fine when I store js files in sharepoint library, but when I reference files which are store in the "app web" (site where the app has it services and sites), this .js files are not loaded. No error, just nothing happens.

How can I reference JSLink file which is out side of sharepoint library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not to do it. Because SharePoint App has isolated architecture. Same situation with host web. You cannot set JSLink property on host web to link of JS file from App web.